# emacs not picking up my init.el file on windows

Tags: emacs

I have my emacs.d folder located at:

```
C:\Users\<loggedin_user>\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d
```

In this folder, I have my init.el file but it is not being picked up by emacs.

Is there another step I am missing, do I need to set an environment variable or something?

When I enter `C-x d ~/ RET` I end up at

```
C:\Users\<loggedin_user>\AppData\Roaming\
```

If I move the init.el file there, it is still not picked up.  I have a deliberate error in the file that is not causing emacs to crash when it is opened.

Comment: Do you maybe also have an `.emacs` file or start your Emacs with `emacs -q` or `emacs --no-init-file`?

Comment: @Mihai I just start with emacs

Comment: `When Emacs is started, it normally tries to load a Lisp program from an initialization file, or init file for short. This file, if it exists, specifies how to initialize Emacs for you. Emacs looks for your init file using the filenames ~/.emacs, ~/.emacs.el, or ~/.emacs.d/init.el; you can choose to use any one of these three names (see Find Init). Here, ~/ stands for your home directory.` See [The Emacs Initialization File](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) So if you do happen to also have an `.emacs` file, it will use that and ignore your `init.el` file

Comment: Set environment variable `HOME`, and put your init file in that folder.

Comment: Well, this question is old, but I faced the same issue today on my Windows 7 and Emacs 27.1. As Mihai and Stefan said, the problem is caused by multiple configuration files. In my particular case Emacs for some unknown to me reason created `.emacs` file in my `AppData\Roaming` and that file took precedence over `init.el` in my `AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d`. After I deleted this `.emacs` file, the problem has gone.

Comment: As @mihai pointed out, I had the issue that having a `.emacs` file, then somehow `.emacs.d/init.el` doesn't seem to be run.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely you have an old ~/.emacs file somewhere else which Emacs ends up using in preference to the other one.

You probably want to check the value of `user-init-file` which will tell you which file Emacs ended up using as "the ~/.emacs file".

I suggest you report this as a bug, requesting that when several files are found as possible init file, Emacs should not just pick the first and ignore the others but should at least emit a warning about the fact that it ignored the others.

Comment: This was my issue too. Had `.emacs` file which was empty and `.emacs.d/init.el` which got ignored. Deleting that `.emacs` file. Did it for me :)

Answer (score 5):

This is tricky on Windows 10 but I solved since I was suffering from same issue.

1. I created an Environment Variable called HOME with the path `C:/user/<username>` in the box "User variables for " create a new one
2. Just open with double click any file that is by default opened with Emacs and it will take few seconds to load then take changed on the init.el
3. create an init.el with just one line of code like:`set-background-color "honeydew"`
   to test this, first before doing something more complex.

Hope That It Helps!

Comment: You saved my time! In my case, it is the missing of %HOME% variable that casued the failure of loading `init.el`.

Comment: Worked perfectly to me as well! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, Emacs is started with some Properties defined, found when you right-click the executable on your windows system. There you can define the

1. execution-directory, e.g. "C:\Users\loggedin_user\" (in parantheses)
2. where emacs executes
3. and looks for the .xemacs (.emacs) directory, where it find its init.el. (I had to create an .emacs File in my Windows Home Directory, which is defined in the Windows HOME Environment)
4. And where you can define the startup instructions (like (setenv "HOME" "c:/Users/Username/") ) etc.

If you configure that, the next time, emacs starts from the directory, you defined, with the initialisation-file

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 and Emacs 27.1 could not find .emacs.d: one more possibility, in my case %HOME% was set like HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%. This redirection seems not to work and emacs was using literally `C:\Users\<loggedin_user>\%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` for searching .emacs.d. I did not dare to edit %HOME% but created link:

```
C:\Users\username> cd %HOME%
```

You perhaps need to remove some files in `C:\Users\<loggedin_user>\%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` which emacs already created.

Create link:

```
C:\Users\<loggedin_user>\%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%> mklink /d .emacs.d ..\.emacs.d
```